# I want to prevent to load when menu is clicked in react-admin. Is it possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-admin

I created simple menu and list view with react-admin.
A left side has three menu item like as 'dashboard', 'Posts' and 'user list'. A main view is display content from left menu item.
Sample code is below as;

```
// App.js
const App = () => (
    <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} icon={PostIcon}/>
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} icon={UserIcon}/>
    </Admin>
);


// Users.js
export class PostActions extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<CardActions>
            <Button color="primary" >Search</Button>
        </CardActions>)
    }
}

export class UserList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<List {...this.props} filters={<UsersFilter/>} actions={<PostActions onSearch={this.props.onSearch}/>}>
            <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
                <TextField source="id"/>
                <TextField source="name"/>
                <TextField source="username"/>
                <EmailField source="email"/>
                <TextField source="address.street"/>
                <TextField source="phone"/>
                <MyUrlField source="website"/>
                <TextField source="company.name"/>
            </Datagrid>
        </List>)
    }
}
```

In upper sample code, main list content is fetched from server when left menu button is clicked.
But I'm trying to view **empty list** view only when I click menu button and **full content** is loaded when I clicked search button in main view made with filters.

[screen capture for menu and list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N6Af.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give you instructions without any code provided, but try to get this:

You can set up a **Loading boolean state** and a **Loading component** ( like a spinning wheel, for example ).

Once you click function triggers, you can set this state to false and **display the Loading Component** while hiding the component that is expecting the data.

Once you request is done, you can **then set the Loading state to false** and hide your Loading Component and display your data.

Comment: The redux message(**RA/CRUD_GET_LIST**) is called when list view is created. How to control this trigger when same event is happened?